# Finding Percentages marks

Tags: python, dictionary, percentage

We have a record of  students. Each record contains the student's name, and their percent marks in Maths, Physics and Chemistry. The marks can be floating values. The user enters some integer  followed by the names and marks for students. We are required to save the record in a dictionary data type. The user then enters a student's name. Output the average percentage marks obtained by that student, correct to two decimal places.

I have tried the following but I am getting an error for some n values

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
    query_score=student_marks[query_name]
    a=(sum(query_score)/n)
    print("{0:.2f}".format(a))
```

Comment: Is the `(backquote) intended? @Abhishek

Comment: oops!! I think its not..removed it but still the error will persist

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Wrong output when n is 2..

Comment: So, its a logical error. We need some input output examples to understand better. @Abhishek

Comment: Can you give an example of a sample input and the expected output please?

Comment: @AbhishekPulicherla Have you tried `print(student_marks)` to see if the data gets stored correctly? And then `print(query_score)` to see if the correct data gets retrieved?

Comment: @Vishnudev   I gave input: 2;Harsh 25 26.5 28; Anurag 26 28 30; Harsh

Comment: And what is the expected output?

Comment: @Ralf Yes!! I have tried

Comment: @SimonFink 26.50 it is

Comment: It is because you devide by the number of entries (2)! Not by the number of grades you enter (3).

Comment: @SimonFink yes got it!! Silly mistake..Thanks so much!!

Comment: Oh god. That small mistake made you write an SO question. Be careful @AbhishekPulicherla.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
    query_score=student_marks[query_name]
    a=(sum(query_score)/len(query_score))
    print("{0:.2f}".format(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    marks = {}
    avg = 0
    scores_sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        marks[name] = scores
   
    query_name = input()
    for i in marks[query_name]:
        scores_sum += i
    
    avg = scores_sum/len(marks[query_name])
    print("{:.2f}".format(avg))
    
        
           
 I was able to execute the above code and it is working fine now.
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python-3

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()

print("%.2f" %(sum(student_marks[query_name])/len(student_marks[query_name])))
```

Input:

```
3
Krishna 67 68 69
Arjun 70 98 63
Malika 52 56 60
Malika
```

Output:

```
56.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = input()


print("{0:.2f}".format(round(sum(student_marks[query_name]) / len(student_marks[query_name]), 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
student_names = {}
stud_name1 =[]
stud_name =[]
final_marks=[]

for studentInfo in range(n):
    stud_name = list(input().split())
    
    stud_name1.append(stud_name)
final_name = input()
      
for m in stud_name1:
    student_names.update({m[0]:{'maths':float(m[1]),'physics':float(m[2]),'chemistry':float(m[3])}})
for n in student_names:
    if final_name == n:
        for subject_name in student_names.get(n):
            final_marks.append(student_names.get(n).get(subject_name))

average = (final_marks[0]+final_marks[1]+final_marks[2])/3
formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(average)
print(formatted_float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = input()
average = sum(student_marks[name])/len(student_marks[name])
average = format(average,'.2f')
print(average)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = input()
query_score = student_marks[query_name]
a = (sum(query_score)/len(scores))
print("{0:.2f}".format(a))
```

Comment: Could you offer an explanation of your code? How does it differ from the existing answers? Under what scenarios might a reader prefer your approach?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this challenge code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
    sum=0
    avg=0
    for key, value in student_marks.items():
      if (key==query_name):
        for i in value:
          sum=sum+i
        avg=sum/len(value)
    print(format(avg,'.2f'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code hereif __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = input()
b = 0
a = student_marks[query_name]
for i in a:
    b = (b + i)

formatted_number = "{:.2f}".format(b / 3)
print(formatted_number)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try that:
if **name** == '**main**':

```
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
   
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = input()

marks = student_marks[query_name]
average_mark = sum(marks) / len(marks)
print("{:.2f}".format(average_mark))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = input()

mark_list = student_marks.get(query_name)
average_mark = round(sum(mark_list)/len(mark_list),2)
result = "{:.2f}".format(average_mark)
print(result)
```